I think so / I would think so/ I would have thought so

Future:

She is going to get married soon, I would think so /I would have thought so/ I think so.

Present:

By the way she behaves, she has much of money, I would think so/I would have thought so/ I think so.

A fact:

A cat can live for 20 years, I would think so /I would have thought so /I think so.

The past:

He stolen his money,I would think so/I would have thought so/I think so.
Question: All examples above are guesses I make about the present, the future, the past. Are these terms used interchangeably?

Not she has much of money, but she has a lot/a great deal of money.

Each example consists of two sentences as it's a dialogue.
Future:

She is going to get married soon.

This is fine:

I would think so/ I  think so.

Would is used to soften an assertion or account for any doubt the speaker may have. This applies also to the other examples here.
I would have thought so can't work but is possible in
I would have thought so if you told me that last year.
Present:
I rephrased a bit:

From the way she behaves, she should have much money.

This is fine:

I would think so/ I think so.

I would have thought so can't work but is possible in
I would have thought so if she didn't speak that loud over the phone and reveal her financial status.
A fact:

A cat can live for 20 years.

This is fine:

I would think so/ I think so.

I would have thought so can't work but is fine in
I would have thought so if I didn’t read further into this topic recently.
(As this part of my answer opposes the lifespan figure, the title A fact would hence not apply here.)
The past:
Please note it is stole, not stolen.

He stole his money.

This is fine:

I would think so/ I think so.

I would have thought so can't work but is fine in
I would have thought so if I didn’t check the CCTV.
In all the examples, would have thought so is accompanied by something that proved the contrary or events that made the answerer change his or her view.

(1) I would have thought so if I DIDN'T check the CCTV.
(2) I would have thought so if I HADN'T checkED the CCTV.
What is the difference between the two?

Hi, @LE123, The sequence of events is clear: first the checking, then the realisation.  Using didn’t check conveys the message clear enough.  It's your choice.
